# Inside an always@(posedge clk) block, having a nested for loop, how do we output for each and every values of i and j?

Tags: image-processing, output, verilog, xilinx, hdl

**Code**

```
integer i,j;

//Luma
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    for (j=0; j<16; j=j+1)  
    begin
        for (i=0; i<16; i=i+1) 
        begin
            Y_pred_h = (16-1-i) * Y_ref_buffer_left[j] + (i+1) * Y_ref_buffer_top_right;
            Y_pred_v = (16-1-j) * Y_ref_buffer_top[i] + (j+1) * Y_ref_buffer_left_bottom;
            Y_Planar_Prediction = (Y_pred_h + Y_pred_v + 16 ) >> (4+1);             
        end
    end
end
```

Here `Y_Planar_Prediction` is my module output, and I need to display its result on screen for each and every value of `i` and `j` in every `posedge` of `clk` (i.e for i=0,j=0 at time=15; i=1,j=0 at time=25; i=2,j=0 at time=35;.....; i=5,j=10 at time=something; ..........; i=15,j=15 at time=something)

But, when I simulate observing the output for only i=15,j=15 (i.e 158) in every posedge of clk.

Attached screenshot for reference:

[image: Undisered output]

How can i modify the code to get:

```
@15ns Y_Planar_Prediction for i=0,j=0; 
@25ns Y_Planar_Prediction for i=1,j=0; 
@35ns Y_Planar_Prediction for i=2,j=0;
and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops in Verilog are merely a convenient way to write concise code.  The `i` and `j` variables are just loop indexes whose values change in a single simulation time step.  The simulation is behaving as expected.  This is not a proper use of `for` loops.

It seems like you really want `i` and `j` to infer logic of counters instead of using `for` loops.  In that case you would need to add new `always` blocks.  For example:

```
reg [3:0] icnt;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (icnt_en) icnt <= icnt + 1;
end
```

In this way, `icnt` will have a new value on each clock cycle.